# Window Size when SizeToContent is not specified

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

When the following XAML used, the window size is not 5000x5000, but some small window where the button is cropped.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" >
    <Button Width="5000" Height="5000">XXX</Button>
</Window>
```

From what I can tell, size I did not specify the SizeToContent attribute, the default is "Manual", so it will use [*size of a window is determined by other properties, including  Width,  Height,  MaxWidth,  MaxHeight,  MinWidth, and  MinHeight. *](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizetocontent.manual.aspx) From the [WPF Windows Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx), it seems those other properties are FrameworkElement::MinHeight/Width, and FrameworkElement::MaxHeight.  But since the default for the Mins are 0, the Maxs are Infinity and the Width/Height is Nan....what's going on? Where is WPF getting the window size?

Any pointers to the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the width and height are not specified WPF uses 60% of the width of you primary screen (where the windows is actually displayed) and 60% of its height. This is done by the Application singleton where all Windows ultimately register themselfes.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything in MSDN that explicitly states what the size defaults are, but the `Top`, `Left` and `WindowStartupLocation` property descriptions say that they default to the normal Win32 defaults if not specified. I think it's reasonable to assume that the `Height` and `Width` properties would do the same.

If you don't want this to happen for your window, then you must explicitly set either the `Width` and `Height` or the `SizeToContent` property of the `Window` element depending on your requirements. The explicit size you set on the `Button` element will only have an effect on the `Window` if `Window.SizeToContent = True`.

Comment: Should say "if Window.SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight." SizeToContent takes an enumeration value, as opposed to boolean. (I assumed it was boolean at first too.)

Comment: It depends on the content. I would set `SizeToContent = WidthAndHeight` if the window was some sort of dialog box, but `SizeToContent = Manual` for a normal application UI window.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the OS has provided the window with these values. It might be related to how Windows OS remembers the size of any window before it was last closed.*

The same way I suppose windows provided a default height and width to your window when none of the dimensions where specified.

- You could try it with notepad. Open it. Resize it. Close it. Now again open it. Hmm..

Comment: not really an answer.  This IS how the "Manual" setting is defined (the size of a window when is is manually resized). The question is WHERE is it being obtained from.

Comment: Notepad is writing and reading its position to registry: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad] This is best practise for most applications including 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

I think the information you're looking for is buried in the documentation for `FrameworkElement.Width` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx)).

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior. In XAML you set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive) to enable the auto sizing behavior. Auto sizing behavior implies that the element will fill the width available to it. **Note however that specific controls frequently supply default values in their default styles that will disable the auto sizing behavior unless it is specifically re-enabled.** [my emphasis]

So, from this, I would expect that the width/height of the Window when there are no other constraints set (such as `MaxWidth`, `MinWidth`, `Width`, etc.) is determined by the default style of a Window.

**Edit:**

Looks like it's more likely it comes from a function called by the `Window` class itself that takes into account all the constraints *plus* the monitor size.