# Why does WPF "height" property behaves like this, when it has "Auto" value?

Tags: c#, wpf

Good afternoon!

I hate to bother you guys, but I have little question about the window "height" property in WPF, when it has "Auto" value. Because I want to understand how the things work here. Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        x:Name="window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Collapsed and Hidden buttons comparison" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Height="50" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0">
            <Button Visibility="Collapsed">This is collapsed button</Button>
            <Button >Below collapsed button</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="50" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0">
            <Button  Visibility="Hidden">This is hidden button</Button>
            <Button >Below hidden button</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I use explicit height like:

```
Height="300"
```

or

```
 SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

before width everything is perfect, but when I don't type or delete default height, the window has this strange appearance.

[image]

In the properties "Height" has value "Auto". And when I use procedural code to get the actualHeight it is 526.

```
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(window.Height),"Height of the window");
```

Can somebody explain please why window behave like this (I mean from where it takes its Height). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is strange here? It has to have *some* height.

Comment: Default height when I create new WPF window is 350, why when I delete this value it becomes exactly 526?

Comment: @MattBurland Yes but I think he is hinting at he expects the height to be 50 or near that of.

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#WindowSize) for some information on how window sizes are calculated. The 350 is just a default from the designer when you create a new window. The 526 is *probably* the default value for `MinHeight`, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @EliArbel: Interesting stuff - you should post it as an answer since I think you are exactly right on what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually outside the realm of WPF. When you use `Double.NaN` (aka `Auto` in XAML) WPF passes `CW_USEDEFAULT` when it calls Win32's [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679). Windows has a certain (*undocumented*) algorithm for placing and sizing windows, and that's what you're seeing.

As Raymond Chen wisely [suggests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/26/10371440.aspx), you cannot rely on such undocumented API, so either use `SizeToContent` or specify a size yourself. Note you can also use the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties.

Answer (score 1):

When you created your window the default height is set to SizeToContent . When **Auto** is specified it takes whatever/or only space it needs. That is to take space as much it is necessary.It is the default value.

You can read more about it [Use Automatic Layout Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748828.aspx#advantages_of_autolayout)

The size of form is very much  related to screen reslution

**EDIT**:

this is intentional and by design:

[MSDN](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/350887/windows-form-clipped-at-run-time-to-screen-resolution)

> Property Form.Size: 
>   The maximum value of this property is limited by
>   the resolution of the screen on which the form runs. The value cannot
>   be greater than 12 pixels over each screen dimension (horizontal + 12
>   and vertical + 12).

Comment: That's not actually true. `SizeToContent` does that, `Auto` does not. Auto just defers to whatever other rules are set (e.g. `MinHeight`, `MaxHeight`).

Comment: Thank you for reply.I understand this. Sorry for perhaps stupid question, but why does it need so much height when I have just 2 StackPanels with Height=50?

Comment: I think this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146106/why-are-my-wpf-window-sizes-defaulting-to-be-huge

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Thanks a lot. It explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I too don't get what M$ is doing behind the scenes, but here's part of my take on height/width of windows... and it gets worse if you are trying to deal with a WPF window based on screen support of different magnifications.  You know when people change their settings for larger text/icon sizes from 100%, 125% and 150%.

Anyhow, what I've found is that when you run a window without a height/width, and it runs in a "Normal" mode, it appears to start up about 3/4 the screen... how/where it determines this default I havent found.  Since you are specifying the width, it is respecting your request of a given width, but appears to retain the "Normal" height.

Now if you use expression blend via

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="350" d:DesignHeight="400"
```

This appear to tell your designer I am expecting the window to be drawn at 350w by 400h.  The "d:" is as stated ignorable so its not FIXED to these dimensions.  So when the form is actually drawn, it does its own voodoo computations to keep the window proportionately sized.

The "d:DesignWidth" and "d:DesignHeight" are DIFFERENT than just a Height/Width declaration, where Height/Width are applied as actual size.

So, this may not exactly explain how/why, but its what I've run into and hope it MIGHT shed some light on what you are encountering.