# How to know why my WPF Window is so big?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, window

I have the following Window created in WPF. This is how it's shown:

[image]

I have no idea why the screen is shown so big and I don't know how to debug why is it getting so wide.

This is the code related to the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="Picis.CpCustomize.CustomizeControls.Dialogs.EditIntegerWindow"
MinWidth="350"
SizeToContent="Height"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
ResizeMode="CanResize" 
ShowInTaskbar="False" 
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
WindowState="Normal"
Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">

<!-- Main frame -->
<Grid>

    <!-- Layout -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100" TextAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Localizer}" ConverterParameter="General.Value" />
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBox x:Name="valueTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>

    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowComments, Converter={StaticResource VisiConv}, ConverterParameter=Collapse}" MinWidth="100" TextAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Localizer}" ConverterParameter="EditParamDlg.Comment" />
            </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBox x:Name="commentTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowComments, Converter={StaticResource VisiConv}, ConverterParameter=Collapse}" Text="{Binding Path=Comment}"/>

    <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" x:Name="isDeletedCheckBox" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowIsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource VisiConv}, ConverterParameter=Collapse}"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDeleted}">
        <CheckBox.Content>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Localizer}" ConverterParameter="EditParamDlg.IsDeleted" />
        </CheckBox.Content>
    </CheckBox>

    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Columns="2">
        <Button  x:Name="okButton" Click="OnOk"  IsDefault="True">
            <Button.Content>
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Localizer}" ConverterParameter="General.Ok" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cancelButton"  Click="OnCancel" Margin="5,0,0,0"  IsCancel="True">
            <Button.Content>
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Localizer}" ConverterParameter="General.Cancel" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </UniformGrid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My first question is how to debug this issue, the second one is what is happening in this specific scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of: [Why are my WPF window sizes defaulting to be huge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146106/why-are-my-wpf-window-sizes-defaulting-to-be-huge)

And according to: [Window Size when SizeToContent is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437099/window-size-when-sizetocontent-is-not-specified) the default size when not specified is 60% of the width and 60% of the height of your primary screen.

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly set the window to stretch in width:

```
SizeToContent="Height"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

This says, "make the window as wide and tall as possible, but then resize to the content of the height"

If you remove that, and set Width and Height to "Auto" (or leave out), you'll likely get what you want.  Try just removing all three of those lines (which will leave out alignment, can cause default Width/Height of "Auto" to be used.)

Comment: But anyway, is there a way to debug this? I get from time to time unexpected results and I haven't found a way to debug them. WPF calculates its things but It should be a way to know why it did what it did, am i right?

Comment: @SoMoS: You can use a tool like Mole (http://www.molosoft.com/) or Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to help ease the process, but nothing that shows you exactly "this is what's causing this to layout this way...", at least not that I've seen.

Comment: Other than the syntax is causing it to layout that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

that is the problem, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems this one:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

It stratches the window...

Answer (score 1):

The alignments on a window should not really do anything as there is no container to reference, but you only tell the window to contract to the content in height, i would change that behavior to both dimensions:

```xml
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

---

How to debug this sort of thing? Maybe train your brain to be able to parse XAML and do layout on the fly... i know, not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is filling existing space (like it is supposed to).

```
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but who created that space? I mean, there is nothing creating it and a * should not create new space right?

Comment: That'll only fill space within the Window - but it's not the root cause.  The root of this problem is the Window declaration itself.

Comment: The ColumnDefinition created that space. And * means takes as much space as available.  I agree with Reed take out the stretch in the top Window section and use Auto for your width.